# 2 dimensional array with multiple values for each x and y

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am looking to create a 2-dimensional array that remaps a texture. So for each pixel it will store a hsv value so that it can be recreated programmatically. (In C# preferrably)
My question is is there an algorithm/code (Linq/ArrayList etc) that would enlarge the resulting array and therefore image - ie: by a factor of ten for example.

Current code for recreating 1 to 1 (this is the loop):

```
imageHueArray = new float[width,height];
for (int i = 0; i < img.width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < img.height; j++)
    {
        imageHueArray[i,j] = pixelH;
    }
}
```

New edit:
I have attempted new code based on some suggestions and links I looked at - I think it is getting closer, but not there yet (any better suggestions appreciated).
I replaced j with z in the array when loops through i in outer loop (as outside j loop).
This code increases size of image, but the increase portion is only blank (or at least using a fixed pixel, 0,0 perhaps) - I think it is in issue with the i/x plane as this does not seem to loop correctly, although the code looks okay (to me).

```
for (var i = 0; i < newRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < newCols; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < resizeScale; k++) {
         imageHueArray[i,j] = pixelHSV;
        }
        z=j;
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < resizeScale; k++) {
        imageHueArray[i,z] = pixelHSV;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course. There are plenty. Depends also if you would like to resize your array or just want to render it to screen or buffer. Research yourself on scaling, interpolation, zoom.

Comment: I wanted to resize the array - so that by re-mapping the array the resulting programmatic image would be ten times larger (ie: from above code each pixelH value would appear ten times more than previously) Nothing to do with rendering, just a pure programming query.

Comment: Then create a new array. Make a loop copying the values "scale factor times".  To make it nicer you may implement lerp (linear interpolation).

Comment: Yes there are algorithms.  But to do properly you would need to use smoothing and it require DSP processing.

Comment: Assuming you understand integer mathematics works, it should be trivial for you to transfer this array to one that is 10x larger - you seem to have those skills. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have looked at some examples mentioned above, and tried to rewrite my code to magnify the array (C# so fixed). I added some resize loops in the x and y planes, but am still not getting it to work. I will edit post above

Comment: Just do it in your shader.

Comment: I can't use a shader because I am using the code to place objects on the screen - I am not trying to resize the image for redisplay. In fact, the whole point is to avoid a larger image/texture before converting it to code.